# How to make a list to keyword list with PHP

Tags: php

I want to do something with PHP .

I have this list of names :

```
first
second 
third
forth
```

Now i want to have this :

```
first,second,third,forth
```

How can this happen with a little PHP code ?

Comment: Are you looking for `implode`?

Comment: What you mean ? please make your correct problem

Comment: before asking question,google first http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_implode

Comment: @Barmar no, i just have a huge list of names in TXT file. i can't put them easily in an php array.

Comment: Why can't you put them in a PHP array? That's what the `file()` function does.

Comment: @Barmar ok thank's . can you give me a little code to import the file and do implode ?

Comment: Isn't it enough to tell you what function you need to use, can't you look it up in the documentation? Anyway, I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have those in array

```
$arr=array('first','second');
$str=implode(",",$arr);
```

EDIT(assuming each names are on the new line, i will replace \n with ,)

```
$str=file_get_contents("filename.txt");
$newstr=str_replace("\n",',',$str);
$newstr=trim($newstr, ",");//to remove the last comma 
echo $newstr;
```

Comment: thanks, but if i have a huge list in TXT file , how can i put them into array ?

Comment: This will probably put a `,` at the end, which probably isn't wanted.

Answer (score 1):

i think you text tag based on new line, so try this

```
first
second 
third
forth 

  $arr = explode("\n", $txt);
  echo implode(",",$arr);
```

every new line consider as a array value.

Comment: thanks, but if i have a huge list in TXT file , how can i put them into array ?!

Comment: can you please paste the sample text what the content in txt file

Comment: i said the main TXT tag is containing a list like i wrote in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is really basic PHP, I can't believe it isn't covered in most tutorials.

```
$array = file("filename", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$string = implode(',', $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for explode, like so https://www.php.net/explode

```
array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )
```

You want to set `$delimiter` to `' '`, `$string` can be a copy -> paste of your text.txt content.

The best thing to do would be: take the text.txt content and use search-replace to remove new lines and add spaces (or commas), so you go from

```
ron
john
kahn
```

to `ron, john, kahn`, at which point you can import an array for use in php.